# Make <li> tags all have the same jquery mousedown/hover effects without individual id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is wrong but i wanted to simulate kind of what im trying to accomplish.

How do I make it so every `<li>` element inside a specific `<ul class="myul">` has the same mousedown/mouseout/hover/etc effects but individually instead of all at once.

Currently if you hover or click on one `<li>` the effect occurs to all of them. I don't want individual id's since the `<li>'s` wont be manually updated - and the number will always vary.

```
 $(".deleteIcon").mouseover(function(){
     $(".deleteIcon").closest('li').css("opacity", "0.7");
 });

 $(".deleteIcon").mouseout(function(){
     $(".deleteIcon").closest('li').css("opacity", "1");
     $(".deleteIcon").closest('li').css("background-color", "#89b8d7");
 });

 $(".deleteIcon").mousedown(function(){
     $(".deleteIcon").closest('li').css("background-color", "#76101c");
 });

 $(".deleteIcon").mouseup(function(){
     $(".deleteIcon").closest('li').css("background-color", "#89b8d7");
 });

<ul>
<li><span>example1.pdf</span><div class="deleteIcon"></div></li>
<li><span>example1.pdf</span><div class="deleteIcon"></div></li> 
<li><span>example1.pdf</span><div class="deleteIcon"></div></li> 
<li><span>example1.pdf</span><div class="deleteIcon"></div></li> 

</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hotswap your `$('.deleteIcon')` queries for the more context-specific `$(this)` query, when inside the handler.

```
$(".deleteIcon")
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').css("opacity", "0.7");
})
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).closest('li').css("background-color", "#89b8d7");
})
.mousedown(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').css("background-color", "#76101c");
})
.mouseup(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').css("background-color", "#89b8d7");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select your list items like so `$("#ulId li")` and then pipe your effects.

```
$("#ulId li").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0.7");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#89b8d7");
}).mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#76101c");
}).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#89b8d7");
});
```

Where `this` is the the `li` you have your mouse hover, out, down & up.

Answer (score -1):

Pure CSS solution:

```
.deleteIcon {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #89b8d7;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
}
.deleteIcon:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.deleteIcon:active {
  background-color: #76101c;
}
```